# Seperation of variables algortithm.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a question for a past paper that asks me to solve using separation of variables:

$y_{tt}$=$y_{xx}$-$y_x$+4y with Dirichlet zero conditions: y(0,t)=y(1,t)=0
 and the initial data: y(x,0)=f(x) and $y_{t}$(x,0)=g(x).
To start this I assume the solution is of the form y(x,t)=U(x)T(t).

I get:
$y_{tt}$=T'', $y_{xx}$=U'' $y_{x}$=U'

So substituting this into the original equation I get:

T''=U''-U'+4UT which can be rearrangedto get:

T''/T=(U-U')T+4U

However, in the model solution it uses that:

T''/T=(U''-U'+4U)/U

I am unsure how you can write it like this and I am unsure if I have made a mistake? If anyone could explain how to get this I will be very grateful.

Comment: Here is a reference of MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 1):

If $y(x,t) = U(x)T(t)$ then the partial derivatives you have given in your question are incorrect. They should be:

$y_{x} = U'(x)T(t)$

$y_{xx} = U''(x)T(t)$

$y_{tt} = U(x)T''(t)$

If you make these substitutions you should recover the model solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is wrong. After substitution, you should get 
$$UT″=U″T−U′T+4UT$$

Notice that the derivative of $UT$ with respect to $t$ is $UT′$. It seems you forgot the $U$, and forgot the $T$ when doing derivative with respect to $x$.